# Server error on ASP NET MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, iis-7.5

I have a problem deploying my ASP NET MVC 4 web-application.

Using Visual Studio 2010 on my local machine, the application works well, but then when I deploy it to IIS 7.5 application, now the application results in a server error.

I setup IIS logging on my site, and look only for info about requests failing with HTTP 500.

Next, I add `nlog` logger and I can see that the application fails on `return View();` in any controllers actions.

I don't understand why the error happens only on the server and how I can fix this problem.

Comment: I solved my problem! Actually, web.config file was changed. On local version builder add new element "dependentAssembly"

Answer (score 0):

Issues that you need to check on

- is the asp.net server role enabled
- do you have the correct version of the .net framework
- does the app pool that your application uses have the correct version of the runtime selected?

Use nuget to install the asp.net mvc 4 package in your web application, in this way, the files needed to support mvc are installed local with your application.